# Wordpress: Random Posts but excluding a single post category

Tags: php, wordpress

I found this PHP code:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'generate_random_category_posts', 100 );
function generate_random_category_posts( $query ) {
    $catto = get_queried_object();
    if ( $query->is_category() && $query->is_main_query() && $catto->term_id === 9 ) {
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'rand' );
    }
}
```

The person was able to randomly display WordPress posts for the chosen category (*9*, in this case). What I would like to do is randomly display all categories except a single chosen category.

I know if I remove

```
IF (if ( $query->is_category() && $query->is_main_query() &&
         $catto->term_id === 9 )
```

it will randomly displays all categories and not just a single one (which is OK), but how would I do it to exclude a single category?

Thanks in advance for you help.

Answer (score 0):

Shortly - replace `category` param with `category__not_in`
Example with get_posts

```
get_posts([
 'order_by' => 'rand',
 'category__not_in' => $exclude_this_category
]);
```

Example based on your code affects all queries, I'd not recommend to use it.
Also `is_category()` means you are already view single category page, better to prevent that user able to visit page with category you want to exclude. But for your example code below should work

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'generate_random_category_posts', 100 );
function generate_random_category_posts( $query ) {
    $catto = get_queried_object();
    if ( $query->is_archive() && !$query->is_category() && $query->is_main_query()) {
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'rand' );
        $query->set( 'category__not_in',  $exclude_this_category );
    }
}
```

More info [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#category-parameters).